# List shows an associated workflow but cant find it under the workflows page

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I recently found many Workflows that are configured in our SharePoint site , under different lists and libraries, which can be seen in both the SharePoint site, under the **list settings** > **workflow settings**.
And also on viewing that configured list in SharePoint designer , It is shown as the workflow associated with the list.

But this workflow could not be found under **Site Objects** > **Workflows** in the SP designer.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?
And is there a way to retrieve it back so that I would be able to edit it or use it else where.

Comment: Is given information useful for you?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have to recreate it... SPD WFs which are not reusable are bound to the list using the "`WorkflowAssociation`" property in the Object Model. Maybe there is a way to read out this association and attach it to a new list.

It may be easier to just recreate it :)